# Sample of filtered twitter api stream

Tags: python, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

I need to get a filtered sample of twitter stream

I'm using tweepy
I checked the functions for the class Stream to get sample stream and to filter

but I dint' catch how should I set the class

should it be

```py
stream.filter(track=['']).sample()
stream.sample().filter(track=[''])
```

or each one in a line or what

And if you have another idea how to get a sample stream based on keyword filters please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Twitter v2 APIs include **an endpoint for random sampling** and **endpoint for filtered tweets**.

The latter allows for specifying a random sample percentage in a query ([for example, sample:10 will return a random 10% sample](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/filtered-stream/integrate/build-a-rule)).

Note that v2 APIs are still new and at the moment have [a cap of 500k tweets per month](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview).

As an example for the latter, the following code ([modified version of this](https://github.com/twitterdev/Twitter-API-v2-sample-code/blob/master/Filtered-Stream/filtered_stream.py), [see this doc](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/stream-tweets-in-real-time)) will collect streaming data with cat or dog tags and store it in a json file for every 100 tweets. (Note: this does not include the random sampling query.)

```
import requests
import os
import json

import pandas as pd
# To set your enviornment variables in your terminal run the following line:
# export 'BEARER_TOKEN'='<your_bearer_token>'


data = []
counter = 0

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers


def get_rules(headers, bearer_token):
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules", headers=headers
    )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))
    return response.json()


def delete_all_rules(headers, bearer_token, rules):
    if rules is None or "data" not in rules:
        return None

    ids = list(map(lambda rule: rule["id"], rules["data"]))
    payload = {"delete": {"ids": ids}}
    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
        headers=headers,
        json=payload
    )
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot delete rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))


def set_rules(headers, delete, bearer_token):
    # You can adjust the rules if needed
    sample_rules = [
        {"value": "dog has:images", "tag": "dog pictures"},
        {"value": "cat has:images -grumpy", "tag": "cat pictures"},
    ]
    payload = {"add": sample_rules}
    response = requests.post(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream/rules",
        headers=headers,
        json=payload,
    )
    if response.status_code != 201:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot add rules (HTTP {}): {}".format(response.status_code, response.text)
        )
    print(json.dumps(response.json()))


def get_stream(headers, set, bearer_token):
    global data, counter
    response = requests.get(
        "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream", headers=headers, stream=True,
    )
    print(response.status_code)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            "Cannot get stream (HTTP {}): {}".format(
                response.status_code, response.text
            )
        )
    for response_line in response.iter_lines():
        if response_line:
            json_response = json.loads(response_line)
            print(json.dumps(json_response, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
            data.append(json_response['data'])
            if len(data) % 100 == 0:
                print('storing data')
                pd.read_json(json.dumps(data), orient='records').to_json(f'tw_example_{counter}.json', orient='records')
                data = []
                counter +=1



def main():

    bearer_token = os.environ.get("BEARER_TOKEN")
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    rules = get_rules(headers, bearer_token)
    delete = delete_all_rules(headers, bearer_token, rules)
    set = set_rules(headers, delete, bearer_token)
    get_stream(headers, set, bearer_token)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Then, load data in pandas dataframe as
`df = pd.read_json('tw_example.json',  orient='records')`.

Comment: Thanks but here is still filtering the main complete stream api
I want to get a sample stream with the api for it, but that stream is filtered upon keywords 

I see that here I determine the number of the tweets based on counter, so I create my own sampling code 
but the sample gives a 1% of the stream and claims to be of wide variation

Comment: @mohsen.21 you are right. V2 API again is separate for sampling streaming vs filtering streaming, not both functions together (and I edited the above answer).   If you are using filtering API, you can write code to sample about 1-2% of the time (say, randomly selected 1 minute interval every hour). If you are using sampling API, you can write code to filter the tweets and store the relevant data.

Comment: how can we get stream of tweets only from posters with 1-10K followers?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading the api documentation for tweepy. [Here](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/streaming_how_to.html#step-3-starting-a-stream) you can see how to filter the stream like you want to.

From reading other code snippets, i belive it should be done like this:

```
stream.filter(track=['Keyword'])
print(stream.sample())
```

Comment: seems like a valid approach
sadly the documentation on tweepy don't go to this point and don't even mention sample stream 
will let you know how it goes

Comment: Yeah, i couldn't find it either. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, `tweepy` uses twitter v1.1 APIs, which has separate APIs for sampling and filtering tweets in real time.

Twitter API references.
[v1 sample-realtime](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/sample-realtime/api-reference/decahose)
[v1 filter-realtime](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/api-reference/post-statuses-filter)

Approach 1: one can get filtered stream data using `stream.filter(track=['Keyword1', 'keyord2'])` etc. and then sample records from the collected data.

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_status(self, status):
        # do data processing and storing here
```

see examples like https://www.storybench.org/how-to-collect-tweets-from-the-twitter-streaming-api-using-python/  [Ignoring Retweets When Streaming Twitter Tweets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43644286/ignoring-retweets-when-streaming-twitter-tweets)

Approach 2: one can write program that starts and stops streaming in random time intervals (for example, random sampling of 3 min interval in every 15 minutes).

Approach 3: one can instead use the sampling API to collect data and then filter with keyword to store relevant data.

Comment: seems like the logical approach
as twitter itself if it did provide the feature would go through the same steps you mentioned 

will still choosing wich approach of the three to take 
the code is very helpful btw thanks

Comment: @mohsen.21  so, later I did find a way to both filter and sample stream via Twitter v2 API. In the filtering streaming, one can also add "sample:10" to get 10% sample of the filtered stream.

Comment: for real that's great 
where it should be added 
like when setting the class of the streamer 
or after launching the filtered stream ?

also is api 2 working with tweepy ?

Comment: @mohsen.21 it's Twitter v2 API, which is still on early access and not used by Tweepy. An example of how to use Twitter V2 API is provided in the script I posted in the another answer. If you want to sample, you can add a query condition like "sample:10" etc.  Because V2 API Filtered Streaming has a 500k tweet cap per month (while V1.1 API Filtered Streaming does not seem to have such a cap), Twitter's documentation actually recommends adding a sampling condition like "sample:10".